# Sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules with support a point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm doing an exercise in algebraic geometry where I have to find an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{G}$ over an algebraic variety $X$ such that the canonical morphism 
$$ (\mathcal{G}^{\mathbb{N}})_x\rightarrow (\mathcal{G}_x)^\mathbb{N}$$
Is not injective.

The problem has as hint to consider $X=\mathbb{A}^1(k)$, $x=0$, a sequence $\{a_n\}\subset \mathbb{A}^1\setminus \{0\}$  and the direct sum of the $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules whose support is the point $a_n$. But I can't figure out who are those modules!

If the support of a sheaf of groups $\mathcal{F}$ is defined as the set of points $x\in X$ such that $\mathcal{F}_x\neq 0$. Then I think that a sheaf has a single point as support iff the sheaf is a skyscraper sheaf. But I can't give an structure of $\mathcal{O}_X$-module to an skyscraper sheaf.

I have an example of such a $\mathcal{G}$ when $X$ is a disjoint union of numerable copies of $\mathbb{A}^1$, but this is not an algebraic variety.

If you can give me an example that works or explain me the hint better I will be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside: if you're paying attention to what notation should mean, then it's $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ that denotes the affine line over $k$; $\mathbb{A}^1(k)$ is merely its set of $k$-points. (more coherently, $\mathbb{A}^1 = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x])$, and like any scheme it is a scheme over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$. For any scheme $X$ over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, we tend to write $X_k$ for its fiber over the unique $k$-point of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, and $X(k)$ for the set of $k$-points)

Comment: I'm surprised that you find an example with $X$ a disjoint union of numerable copies of $\mathbb{A}^1$ since this is a local phenomena and you can restrict the left hand side and the right hand side to a single copy. In other words, your example should also work with only one copy... A skyscraper sheaf supported on $\{x\}$ can be written $i_*k$ (with $i_*$ being the inclusion of $\{x\}$), maybe this can help to show that this is a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. (Think of the map $(f,\lambda)\mapsto f(x)\lambda$.)